# Variance of the weighted sum of two random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question with regards to the variance of the weighted sum of two random variables.
Let's define $X$ as follows: 
$$X = \begin{cases} Y, &\text{ with probability } p\\ Z, & \text{ with probability } 1-p \end{cases}$$

How can I calculate the variance of $X$?

Thanks in advance :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(X)=pE(Y)+(1-p)E(Z)$

$E(X^2)=pE(Y^2)+(1-p)E(Z^2)$

$var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$

Simplifying we get $$\sigma_Z^2=p\sigma_Y^2+(1-p)\sigma_Z^2+p(1-p)(\mu_Y-\mu_Z)^2$$

As noted by Bernard below, the above represents the decomposition of the total variance into expected conditional variance and variance of conditional expectation (using Bernoulli variable $I$ that selects $Y$ or $Z$ for $X$).

Comment: Can you take the weighted sum also of the second moment?

Comment: It's a weighted sum of variances (not second moments) with a correction factor that reflects how much $Y$ and $Z$ differ on average. See updated comment.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the solution is given by the [Law of Total Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance). This law also takes into account that $Y$ and $Z$ might not be independent.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Let $I,J$ be [Bernouilli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) distributed with parameter $p$ and $q:=1-p$.

This with  $I+J=1$.

Write $X=IY+JZ$ where $I,Y$ are independent and $I,Z$ are independent.